# Surjectivity of tensor product map

Tags: galois-theory, tensor-products

This lemma can be found in "[Noether's Problem in Galois Theory](https://books.google.hu/books?id=8iPoBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=bryn+mawr+noether%27s+problem&source=bl&ots=zOJtfcPgEl&sig=Gbd53dwVSwRE2qMO40-yVQ8r_UE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBGoVChMI0eLL0PCKyQIVhJEsCh2evw3V#v=onepage&q=bryn%20mawr%20noether's%20problem&f=false][1])" by Richard Swan on page 27-28.

[image]

In this context, $A = k[x_1,\dots,x_n](1/s)$ for some $s \in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, and this is a Galois extension in the sense of a commutative ring.

It can be shown that if $B/A$ is a Galois extension of commutative rings, then $F \otimes_k B/F\otimes_kA$ is as well. But where I'm confused is the statement $B \to F\otimes_{A,f} B$ is onto. Is the $B$ in $F \otimes_{A,f} B$ also replaced? If not, then the surjectivity makes perfect sense ($F \otimes_k B \to F\otimes_{A,f}B$), but then how can he claim that $c$ can be written as $1 \otimes b$ for $b \in B$? Wouldn't it be $\alpha \otimes b$ for some $\alpha \in F$? Or in this case, could you somehow take the $\alpha$ over to the other side?

Alternatively, can one show that $F \otimes_{F \otimes_{k} A,f} (F \otimes_k B) \cong F \otimes_{A,f} B$?

Any help would be appreciated.